# Google chrome Javascript debugger

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, inspector

is it possible to reload the content of the viewport without reloading the whole inspector.

I would like to make some changes to a javascript file in the debugger then reload the page to see the temp changes I have made (on load), before I commit to the file and upload. Where I'm working at the moment there is caching I can't get round so I have to wait a minute or two to see what my changes do on load.

I have found the page I want to work with under source and can save changes, but really need to see some actions that are fired on the loading of the page.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve exactly, however some tabs have a 'preserve log' checkbox which will retain captured data between refreshes/page loads. There's also a 'disable cache' checkbox which will save you waiting between requests

Comment: No, I'm not sure that's possible.  It sounds like you may need to work on a better debugging experience in your situation - a dev copy of your website without the intermediary cache etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do that with chrome debugger tool. each JS resource will reload on page load so you will loose your change.

you can proxy tools like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) which will allow you to load script from your local machine while loading a third party website. You can create a copy on your own machine and then use fiddler to intercept the call for that file and send your local copy instead

Comment: Thanks, thought as much.